# Connection to server keeps failing connect ETIMEDOUT 94.195.191.104:27017

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Each time I try to connect to my server to access the documents in the database, it comes back with a connect ETIMEDOUT error.

I own the server, running Mongo 4.0, have run mongod and left running, there is data in the collection.

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let uri = "mongodb://notmyrealusername:notmyrealpassword@thomas.misson.info/tom-portfolio";

MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, async function(err, db) {
    try{
        if (err) throw err;
        let res = await db.collection("projects").find().count()
        console.log(res);
        db.close();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }  
});
```

Error message:

```
{ MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 94.195.191.104:27017
    at Socket.err (H:\Documents\Personal projects\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connect.js:287:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

I have opened the port using `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open mongod port 27017" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=27017`

Have now added new interface to the mongod.cfg file.

`# network interfaces net: 
port: 27017 
bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 94.195.191.104`

Comment: Sounds like the port isn't open on the `thomas.misson.info` server. Perhaps mongod is binding to the local interface, or you have a firewall set up, or...

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I believe I have opened the port, i have run `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open mongod port 27017" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=27017` and have no changes.

Comment: Did you check what interface mongod is using? It could be bound to localhost rather than your public interface.

Comment: I have made these changes in the config file: `# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 94.195.191.104`

Comment: Be sure to edit all this information into the question.

Comment: No differences in the error

Comment: Do you use a ':', '@', '%' or '/' in your username or password and if so did you use percent-encoding for them?

Comment: No, nothing like that, just alphanumeric characters

Comment: ensure you have restarted the mongo server after your conf file modifications (involving bindIp)
On the server itself, try to connect to your shell with mongo ```mongodb://yourcreds@127.0.0.1``` and ```mongo mongodb://yourcreds@94.195.191.104```
we expect to fail __only__ on the later one. (it is the case?)
I would then say almost for sure it is a prob of firewall